# how to split tuples into two lists?

Tags: python

The function `foo` below takes in a number and returns a tuple of strings. Can I write the following loop as a one-liner?

```
r1 = []
r2 = []
for i in range(10):
  (s1, s2) = foo(i)
  r1.append(s1)
  r2.append(s2)

# r1 now has the first returned strings from each iteration of the loop, and similarly for r2
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to do this simple

```
r1, r2 = map(list, zip(*foo))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
def foo(i):
    return (i,i+1)
r1, r2 = [tpl for tpl in zip(*map(foo,range(10)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
r1, r2 = map(list, zip(*[foo(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

By passing a list of tuples as args to `zip` (using `*` to convert the list into a list of args), you can "unzip" them.  Map the `list` function over the resulting tuples and you have your two lists.

Comment: I think you could even replace `[foo(i) for i in range(10)]` with `map(foo, range(10))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(i):
    return ("A%d" % i, "B%d" % i)

# This is the one-liner
[r1, r2] = map(list, zip(*(foo(i) for i in range(10))))

print(r1)
print(r2)
```

`zip` takes an M of sequences of N items, and returns N sequences of M items. By taking the sequence generated by the comprehension expression in the and putting a `*` before it, I convert it into 10 separate sequences of two elements. The mapping to `list` is just to make all results into lists.